# How to Compare values of a single hashMap, without using other collections

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, compare

```
m.put("A", al); 
m.put("B", al1);
m.put("C", al2);
```

I want to compare all the values of this HashMap. This is the HashMap with the `String` type keys and `ArrayList<Integer>` type values.

I don't want to use other collection type.

---

```
        Integer a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        Integer b[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        Integer c[] = { 9, 5, 3, 7 };
        Integer d[] = { 1, 2, 3, 2};
        List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(a);
        List<Integer> m = Arrays.asList(b);
        List<Integer> n = Arrays.asList(c);
        List<Integer> o = Arrays.asList(d);
        Map<String, List<Integer>> m1 = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>();
        m1.put("A", l);
        m1.put("B", m);
        m1.put("C", n);
        m1.put("D", o);
```

This is my hashmap m1, and each key has an ArrayList of elements, as we know key "A" and Key "B" both have same elements
            A- {1,2,3,4} and B- {1,2,3,4} and rest of other Keys have different-different elements. so what i want is, to get  all the keys having 
            same  elements. for example Key A and Key B both have same elements so i want to print A and B. and the Size should be same for all the Keys 
            here size is 4 for all the hasmap keys

Comment: You want to compare the values of the hashmap with what exactly? Can you elaborate about your requirements?

Comment: want comparison among all the has values... i want to extract all the duplicate values from this hashMap. 
like all the values of al will be compared to al1 and al2, and so on, comparison will be done among all the elements. i need all the duplicates values with its key

Answer (score 0):

If you use a hashmap there's no possible way you can have two duplicates - if you use it correctly, that is.

For instance, let's use your example.

```
HashMap<String, myClass> hash = new HashMap<String, myClass>();
myClass al = new myClass();
myClass al1 = new myClass();
myClass al2 = new myClass();
```

We have two ways to proceed from here. One, is what you're doing.

```
hash.put("A", al);
hash.put("B", al1);
hash.put("C", al2);
```

It seems flawless, but what if I did this now?

```
hash.put("D", al);
```

This would work perfectly, but this is not how you're supposed to use it. The most basic way to use correctly a hashmap is as follows:

```
hash.put(al.toString(), al);
hash.put(al1.toString(), al1);
hash.put(al2.toString(), al2);
```

Even if you don't redefine the `toString()` method in your class, you will get a unique identifier for that specific instance. `al.toString()` and `al1.toString()` won't return the same value since it depends on the instance.

Now you can also `@Override` the method and let it return whatever string you want it to.

However there's no need to search for duplicate values. If you use a hashmap correctly, the map itself will do it for you.

Comment: Depends on what you use the HashMap for. If you use it for fast access, then you're right. If you use it to "map" certain keys to certain values (for instance names to phone numbers), then `hash.put("D", al);` is completely fine...

Comment: It's not just fast access. The key can also be used to avoid duplicates, which is what OP wants to do.

Comment: He never stated that he wants to avoid duplicates. He just wants to find them. If the only reason is to avoid duplicated, you should yous HashSet and not HashMap...

Answer (score 0):

```
    Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> m= new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> al1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> al2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> all= new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<String> all1= new ArrayList<String>();
    al.add(1);al.add(2);al.add(3);al.add(4);al1.add(1);
    al1.add(2);al1.add(3);al2.add(1);
    al2.add(2);al2.add(3);al2.add(4);
    m.put("A", al);m.put("B", al1);m.put("C", al2);
    Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map1 = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    map.putAll(m);
    for(Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> entry : m.entrySet())
    {   
        for(Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> entry1 : map.entrySet())
        {
           if (!entry.getKey().equals(entry1.getKey())) 
           {
             if (entry.getValue().equals(entry1.getValue())) {

                 map1.put(entry1.getKey(), entry1.getValue());
            }
           }
           else {
               if (map1.isEmpty()) {
                       map1.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                    }
                   else {
                       if (map1.containsValue(entry.getValue())) {
                       map1.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                       }
                }
                }

        }
        }
```

i got the solution for this.. thanks guys :)